# Assign a property to a Silex app for unit testing

Tags: php, phpunit, silex

I'm trying to unit test a Silex application.
This is the code I'm testing:

```
use Silex\Application;

class MyUser
{
    public function run(Application $app)
    {
        // show what $app['env'] actually contains
        var_dump($app['env']);

        if ($app['env'] == 'prod') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }       
    }
}
```

I made the following test class:

```
class TestMyUser extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function setup()
    {
        $this->app = $this->getMockBuilder('\Application')
                     ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                     ->getMock();

        $this->myUser = new MyUser();
    }

    public function testRun()
    {
        $this->app['env']    = 'prod'; // this outputs NULL
        $this->app->env      = 'prod'; // this outputs NULL
        $this->values['env'] = 'prod'; // this throws an error saying that values is a protected property
        $result = $this->myUser->run($this->app);
        $this->assertEquals(true, $result); // will always fail as $app['env'] is NULL
    }

}
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to assign a property to the mocked application.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make the "values" mock property accesible:

```
public function testRun()
{
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($this->myUser);
    $reflection_property = $reflection->getProperty('values');
    $reflection_property->setAccessible(true);

    $values = $reflection_property->getValue('values');
    $values['env'] = 'prod';
    $reflection_property->setValue('values', $values);

    $result = $this->myUser->run($this->app);
    $this->assertEquals(true, $result); // will always fail as $app['env'] is NULL
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I still get NULL for $app['env']. I don't think changing the 'values' property of the Reflection Class eventually changes the mocked Application object.

Comment: You are actually changing the Application object by using a Reflection class. But maybe it does not work in a Mock object.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this myself. When you create that mock as per your code example, it doesn't implement any of Application's methods. If you want the methods to still be present in the mock, you need to adjust your mocking thus:

`$this->app = $this->getMockBuilder('\Application')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(null) // you need this
    ->getMock();`

Giving [`setMethods`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.tables.matchers) `null` will mean not to mock-out any of its methods. I'd've thought not calling `setMethods` at all would have the same effect, but: no.

When you do this:

`$this->app['env'] = 'prod';`

it's calling Application's [`offsetSet`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetset.php) method, so the method needs to be there.